# Is store liable for "abandoning" my laptop left for repair?

Tags: consumer-protection, theft

I dropped off my MacBook Pro for repair at the local Apple Store, letting them know I wouldn't be in town for another 3 months-ish.

After a month, they started contacting me via email and phone to tell me it's ready for pickup. In response I called the Apple Store to notify them again that I wouldn't be in town until thanksgiving week.

Now, during Black Friday I tried to pick it up and they told me they abandoned it and it is already recycled. The manager let me know there isn't much they can do. They were super friendly and very sorry, but for some reason they didn't have any notes that I'd come pick it up again.

Is there anything I can do to get some sort of compensation?

Comment: First instinct would be probably not unless you've got documentary evidence that you did tell them (otherwise it would be you-said, they-said). But IANAL and local laws may say something different (you should probably add the location to the question).

Comment: Documentary evidence will be key that you called, sent emails, etc. Failing that, Tim Cook's email address is public - tcook@apple.com - and he answers his email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a store sell merchandise I've left in the store?](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14273/can-a-store-sell-merchandise-ive-left-in-the-store)

Comment: Evidence of the OP's notice to the bailee  (express/implied acceptance thereof) that a period of time would elapse before he (OP) would come along and retrieve his property will be crucial, as will be the law of abandonment and whether it applies here. The question of any abandonment by OP is a 'sine qua nom', not the so called "abandonment" [sic] by the baliee.

Comment: It is in Houston, Texas. The Store said they don't have any evidence of my call. If I had known that there is a chance of leaving no evidence by calling I clearly would have emailed. This is just too bad...